# How to hide foreground-brought nohup process background again

Tags: linux, background, foreground, nohup

I bring a nohup background process foreground use "fg" by accident, now my screen is stucked there waiting the nohup process to be completed. It seems that it won't accept any user input, how to bring the nohup process background again?

Thank you all in advance